# How to architect a calendar in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

As a little toy project, I'm trying to build a simple calendar in EmberJS (just a frontend app, using the Fixture adapter).

I guess I'll need to define two models; a 'day' model with a hasMany relationship to an 'appointment' model.

The trouble I'm having is creating all of the 'day' models when the application boots. How would I go about that? I'd like to have a month-view (starting with the current month) so I don't really want to use pre-defined FIXTURES to create my 'days'.

How can I create the days programmatically on application initialization? I've tried doing it on the store's load event, with a seperate function called by a method on my controller (appears to load the data, but can't access it from templates for some reason...).

Am I going the right way by creating an object for each day, or is there a more 'Ember' way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question ***"Am I going the right way by creating an object for each day, or is there a more 'Ember' way to do this?"*** The Ember way *is* the way of the object - so YES.

To answer the ***"How to do it?"*** question: There are many ways. One approach is to to generate all the 'calendar dates' using an Ember ArrayController and the Date object or some other date library (moment.js is great) and render a CollectionView that will display the data. Each calendar day needs to be bound to a model representing the users 'content' for that day. Then you will need to load your model (data for each day) into an ArrayController. If you have your Routing and 'needs' right, you should see the data appear for each day when the data has finished loading.

This may also help: The model for a 'calendar' is already implemented (by the Date object); you will need to generate the list of days using it, and bind the fixture data to them. So, you will only need fixtures to represent the user's data for each 'calendar date'. Each 'calendar date' model will have many 'calendar items'.

I am currently working on an Ember app that has a calendar component, and wrestled to get started as well. Hope this helps you get rolling some!

Answer (score 0):

Theres many different ways to do this but for the sake of a toy project you could just create them in the ApplicationRoute.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  setupController: function(model, controller) {
    //create your days here
    App.Day.createRecord({key: 'value'});
  }

});
```

Then when you call App.Day.find() elsewhere in your application these days will show up.